# Could not save the one menu list

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm using jsf 2.2 and i tried to save the selected value into my database but i always get : Erreur of conversion of the value «1» pour «null Converter».

i need to insert the ID of the medical act in the foreign key field of the demand.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Ajouter Demande</title>

</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:panel header="Actes médicaux">
            <p:messages id="messages" />


            <p:tab title="Utilisateur">

                <h:panelGrid id="grid1" columns="2" cellpadding="5" layout="grid"
                    styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">

                    <p:outputLabel for="console" value="Type de l'acte médical:" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{demandeBean.demande.actemedical}"
                        style="width:125px">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{acteMedicalBean.listacte}" var="acte" itemLabel="#{acte.typeActeMedical}" 
                        itemValue="#{acte.idActeMedical}"
                        />

                    </p:selectOneMenu>


                    <p:commandButton immediate="true" value="+">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton update="form" value="Sauvegarder" id="button"
                        actionListener="#{demandeBean.save()}"
                        style="background:#6FDC6F;color: #FFFFFF;float:right"
                        styleClass="customStyleButton">

                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Êtes-vous sûr?"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
                            <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button"
                                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button"
                                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                        </p:confirmDialog>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGrid>

            </p:tab>
        </p:panel>


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>



   package com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.entities;

// default package
// Generated 5 avr. 2017 16:43:08 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Demande generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEMANDE", catalog = "ASSURANCE")
public class Demande implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idDemande;
    private Actemedical actemedical;
    private Utilisateur utilisateur;
    private Demande demande;
    private Double montantDemande;
    private Date dateDemande;
    private String etatDemande;
    private Set<Demande> demandes = new HashSet<Demande>(0);

    public Demande() { actemedical = new Actemedical();
    }

    public Demande(Actemedical actemedical, Utilisateur utilisateur, Demande demande, Double montantDemande,
            Date dateDemande, String etatDemande, Set<Demande> demandes) {
        this.actemedical = actemedical;
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
        this.demande = demande;
        this.montantDemande = montantDemande;
        this.dateDemande = dateDemande;
        this.etatDemande = etatDemande;
        this.demandes = demandes;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "ID_DEMANDE", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getIdDemande() {
        return this.idDemande;
    }

    public void setIdDemande(Integer idDemande) {
        this.idDemande = idDemande;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID_ACTE_MEDICAL")
    public Actemedical getActemedical() {
        return this.actemedical;
    }

    public void setActemedical(Actemedical actemedical) {
        this.actemedical = actemedical;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_MATRICULE_UTILISATEUR")
    public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return this.utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ID_ACTE_MEDICAL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Demande getDemande() {
        return this.demande;
    }

    public void setDemande(Demande demande) {
        this.demande = demande;
    }

    @Column(name = "MONTANT_DEMANDE", precision = 17, scale = 0)
    public Double getMontantDemande() {
        return this.montantDemande;
    }

    public void setMontantDemande(Double montantDemande) {
        this.montantDemande = montantDemande;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE_DEMANDE", length = 8)
    public Date getDateDemande() {
        return this.dateDemande;
    }

    public void setDateDemande(Date dateDemande) {
        this.dateDemande = dateDemande;
    }

    @Column(name = "ETAT_DEMANDE", length = 100)
    public String getEtatDemande() {
        return this.etatDemande;
    }

    public void setEtatDemande(String etatDemande) {
        this.etatDemande = etatDemande;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "actemedical")
    public Set<Demande> getDemandes() {
        return this.demandes;
    }

    public void setDemandes(Set<Demande> demandes) {
        this.demandes = demandes;
    }

}



  package com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.entities.Actemedical;
import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.entities.Demande;
import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.services.ActemedicalService;
import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.services.DemandeService;
import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.services.imp.ActemedicalServiceImp;
import com.sopra_hr.GestionRemboursement.services.imp.DemandeServiceImp;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class DemandeBean implements Serializable{

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DemandeBean.class);
    private Demande demande = new Demande();
    private Actemedical acte = new Actemedical();
     private DemandeService demandeService = new DemandeServiceImp();
     private ActemedicalService acteService = new ActemedicalServiceImp();
     private List<Demande> listdemandes = new ArrayList<Demande>();
     private List<Actemedical> listactes = new ArrayList<Actemedical>();





    @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
         try {
             listdemandes =demandeService.findAll();
             listactes =acteService.findAll();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


    public void save() {

        try {
            demandeService.save(demande);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "", "Demande ajouté avec succes"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "", "Erreur d'insertion"));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public Demande getDemande() {
        return demande;
    }


    public void setDemande(Demande demande) {
        this.demande = demande;
    }


    public Actemedical getActe() {
        return acte;
    }


    public void setActe(Actemedical acte) {
        this.acte = acte;
    }


    public DemandeService getDemandeService() {
        return demandeService;
    }


    public void setDemandeService(DemandeService demandeService) {
        this.demandeService = demandeService;
    }


    public List<Demande> getListdemandes() {
        return listdemandes;
    }


    public void setListdemandes(List<Demande> listdemandes) {
        this.listdemandes = listdemandes;
    }


    public List<Actemedical> getListactes() {
        return listactes;
    }


    public void setListactes(List<Actemedical> listactes) {
        this.listactes = listactes;
    }


}
```

Comment: there no problem of converter but i'm sure that is a problem of configuration of the entity demand like creating instance or change lazy to eager

Comment: In that case it is not jsf, primefaces or selectonemenu related